# What can I use to drive charge and discharge high-side N-channel MOSFETs?

Tags: gate-driving, charge-pump, cell-balancing

I want to control the charge and discharge MOSFETs of the series cells balancing circuit. There is a charge pump to do that but I do not know how to design such a charge pump. Is there any source regarding the design of the charge pump to drive back-to-back charge and discharge MOSFETs?

Thank you

Comment: _”but I do not know how to design such a charge pump”_ Have you tried searching for it?

Comment: If you don't need fast switching speed, you can use photovoltaic gate drivers, which makes for a much simpler design. e.g. https://www.vishay.com/docs/83469/vom1271.pdf

Comment: Did you see any application notes or reference designs online?